# Magento error when product added to cart Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "1698" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9

We have upgraded the site to latest version 1.9.3.7.

After upgrade only some times we are getting the following error

> a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id
>   "1698" already exist";i:1;s:5317:"#0
>   /home/bagatelleboutiqu/upgrade.bagatelleboutique.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(265):
>   Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))

can anyone help me on this issue

thanks